# PHP send email by CLI

Tags: php, email, exec, command-line-interface

I want to send an email after some services end, so I am using php exec() function to do that

The command I use is: `exec('(other service commands; /usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/email.php name@domain.com) > /dev/null &');`

email.php contains a mysql update and a mail() function. It seems to be working well as the mysql update is happening but it doesn't send the email.

If I run the command via CLI and not via php exec(), the email is sent correctly.
eg. `/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/email.php receiver@domain.com`

Is there anything else I should set up to fix that?

Comment: instead of redirecting the output to /dev/null, you could redirect it to a file, maybe you can read what's going on straight from the file

Comment: the problem is in permissions: try to use cli command with `sudo -u wwwuser /usr/bin...` - you should see this not working

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it!

Apparently, `sendmail_path` on CLI's php.ini (`/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`) was commented out.

I uncommented it, set it's value as `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i`, restarted apache and now it works properly!